# How to create Html to pdf on particular div onclick button in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, pdf, html2canvas

I am new to AngularJS, and I want to create a pdf of a particular div with a button click. Currently I'm having code that works on page load. If I
refresh the page it will automatically download that particular div. But I need the download to happen after the click event. This is
my code. Please help me. I have added necessary scripts of html2canvas etc.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function in your controller, and add a click event to a button.

Your view:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="createPdf()" value="Create PDF"/>
```

Your controller:

```
$scope.createPdf = function () {

    html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
        }
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

js click event

```
function myClick() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      }
  });
}
```

html

```
<input type="submit" id="testhtm2canvas" onclick="myClick()" value="html2"/>
```